# Question is visible in questions/tagged/foo but missing in questions/tagged/foo%20or%20bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, specific-question

I noticed a strange behaviour regarding this question: [`What is the difference between A<T extends B> and A<? extends B>?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211548/what-is-the-difference-between-at-extends-b-and-a-extends-b).

When I navigate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java, it's visible:

[image]

whereas in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java%20or%20spring it's missing

[image]

In both cases sort order is "newest". Also screenshots show it happening on "xx mins ago" -> "1 hour ago" border, but I observed it when the following question was "xx mins ago" too.

I tried different browsers, so it doesn't look like a browser cache problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great catch -- this was a massive error in the way suggested edits was writing tags to the database (the post in question had a new tag added through a suggested edit).

Now fixed!